# how separate files from an uncompressed zlib stream

Tags: stream, zlib, separator

I have buffered a zlib stream in a std:vector.
I have uncompressed programmatically this stream in a new std:vector named "UncompressedZlibStream".

I know that my stream contains multiple files.
I would like to knwo how "cut" (separate) my files in the stream.

I think zlib use a separator ? but why caracter or sequence !?

Anyone have any informations about this ?

Thanks a lot,

best regards,

CrashOverHead

Answer (score 0):

Zlib itself is only a compression library. It is typically only used to compress a single file. Putting multiple files into zlib requires that you use a format like tar and then compress the result. Zlib compressed tar files are pretty common in the Unix world. You may want to have a look at [LibTar](http://www.destructor.de/libtar/index.htm). If it's anything else it's likely proprietary and you're kind of on your own for how to dice the stream.